# First Bootstrap project, how do I make container widths equal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, boot

student here working on one of my final projects. First time using Bootstrap. I am having difficulty making my content match the same width as my navigation. You can see the project live [here](http://www.hardcoded.ca/cp/html/) to see what I am talking about.

I built the grid first and then attempted to create my own styles in a file called **style.css**.

What I have tried to do is create a class like so:

```
.container .no-padding-lr {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

and apply it to my markup:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 no-padding-lr">
   <h1 class="intro">Your online Canadian-built Pontiac, Acadian, and Beaumont Resource.</h1>
   <img class="img-responsive img-rounded no-padding-lr" src="assets/images/DSCN8314.JPG" alt="pontiac header" />
</div>
```

As you can see it is only widening maybe 50% of what is required.

How can I adjust it so the content is all in line with one another?

Comment: The first thing i can see you need to put the columns inside rows.

Comment: @wazaaaap I thought I did? Am I mistaken in how they are supposed to be used?

Comment: Read a little about the bootstrap grid system here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: `<div class="row">`  Why do you use this?

Comment: @HelloNewWorld Ah, to expand horizontally! But I seemed to have buggered it up after updating the live link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap all the col-*-* divs with a `<div class="row">`.

Quoting the [relevant bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> - Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) **for proper alignment and padding**.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Comment: Thank you. I was using it incorrectly after all. I have gone and adjusted my code (which is live) but I think I am doing something wrong still...

Comment: @JonathanMusso keep all your `row`s in a `container`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as noted above, you need to nest any column div inside of a row div (I can't comment because this is my first post on stackoverflow). This adds margin-left:-15px and margin-right:-15px to your columns, making them 750px/100% width.